# Magento 2: Can't update product page layout in custom theme

Tags: magento2, theme

(heavily modified the question for simplicity and clarity)

As a test case, I created `<custom-theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`. Creating and modifying this file, according to the docs, should affect every page.

In my extended `default_head_blocks.xml` I added a bogus JS, just to see what pages it will be added to.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/test-file.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

I can see `test-file.js` on category and CMS pages, but not on a product page.

I can't get any layout updates to affect the product page. The product page has the inherited theme `Magento Blank`, plus my site logo, located in `<theme-dir>/web/imges/logo.svg`.

Any guidance on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Please review the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html) and let us know if it's helpful or not.

Comment: Hi, if you'll provide your layout XML here, we can help you. Thanks

Comment: Take a theme based on Magento Blank, and create `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` and create     

    `<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <move element="page.main.title" destination="product.info.main" after="-"/>
        </body>
    </page>`

and nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

There was similar issue with a custom layout file not being applied:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2996

One of the community members solved an issue with custom layout file not being applied by changing line endings to unix and encoding to utf8 in his custom layout.

Comment: Great suggestion, but best I can tell, my files are utf-8 encoded and use unix line endings. I am developing on MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the composer.json in your theme if not created yet.

```
{
    "name": "vendor_name/theme_name",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-blank": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "2.2.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

Then, run below command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score -1):

Product Page layout in magento2 have to set from product. Edit the product from backend and set it to 1 column.

[image: Edit the product]